# Endianness of HMAC-SHA code

Tags: encryption, sha, hmac, endianness

I am transmitting AES messages.  My understanding is that:  1. The AES algorithm treats messages as byte-wise and is endian-neutral.  2. The Initialization Vector is endian-neutral as far as transmission and reception is concerned.

I am also calculating an HMAC-SHA384 code for the message.  From my reading it sounds as though HMAC-SHA384 **does** need byte-swapping if the transmission endianness (big-endian in my case) does not match machine endianness.  The swapping should occur from byte 0 and 47, 1 and 46, so on?  Can anyone more knowledgeable in the subject than I confirm or contradict this please?

I am presently using the .NET HMACSHA384 class, but on the other end I will be writing C++ code and don't yet know what library will provide the HMAC code.

Comment: Endianess does not matter if you are dealing with byte arrays.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, Wiley.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

leppie is right, both are send as byte arrays. And you can be pretty sure that the byte array received will conform to NIST specifications and test vectors. So you should not overly worry about endianness in this case.

If there are people that need to worry then it is the implementors of the hash function. E.g. NIST unfortunately specified a little endian machine (Intel processor) as reference platform for SHA-3. The first version of Skein had incorrect test vectors because of a bug regarding endianness in the first iteration (1.0).

Comment: In case you are still confused, if you have a hexadecimal test vector supplied by NIST then the leftmost byte is the byte with the lowest index. If only a part of a hash is required then the leftmost bytes are taken.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are saying that all proper implementations of SHA-384 should produce a little-endian formatted byte-array because that would comply with the reference platform?

Comment: No, internally it is big endian. The end result is just a bunch of bytes. In the specification the "first byte" can be considered the leftmost byte. After that it is implementation specific. The only real information about this is the FIPS 180-2 standard, part 3 to be exact.